# js синтаксис... Ошибка генерируется

Tags: javascript

```
// Структура:
class OHLCTime {
  constructor() {
    this.Open = null;
    this.High = null;
    this.Low = null;
    this.Close = null;
    this.Time = null;
  }
}



// Фрагмент проблемного кода:
let first = [];
let firstIndex = 0;
let second = [];
let secondIndex = 0;
let count = 0;
let temp = "";
for (let i = 0; i < firstHistory.length; ++i) {
  if (firstHistory[i] != ";") {
    temp += firstHistory[i];
  }
  else {
    if (count == 0) {
      count++;
      first[firstIndex] = new OHLCTime();
      first[firstIndex].Open = temp;
      temp = "";
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
      count++;
      first[firstIndex].High = temp;
      temp = "";
    }
    else if (count == 2) {
      count++;
      first[firstIndex].Low = temp;
      temp = "";
    }
    else if (count == 3) {
      count++;
      first[firstIndex].Close = temp;
      temp = "";
    }
    else { // == 4
      count == 0;
      first[firstIndex++].Time = temp;  // Здесь сервер указывает на ошибку в этой строке.
      temp = "";
    }
  }
}
count = 0;
```

---

Текст ошибки: TypeError: Cannot set property 'Time' of undefined
    at /var/www/www-root/data/www/invizzz.com/nodejs/listenMQL.js:498:80
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)

Comment: firstIndex++ - похоже на выход за пределы массива и попытка обратиться к свойству Time у undefined.

Comment: Только заметил count == 0;  пзд... Щас посмотрю... Выход за пределы он бы написал бы в ошибке... Да и тут наоборот я расширяю массив, а не читаю... Поэтому выход может быть только при чтении.

Comment: @Alex Krass, ну да, ошибка была в count == 0. А я пол часа рассматривал и не понимал ничего...аххах

Comment: Это потому что у вас Time не определено. У меня Time определяется всегда, когда count == 0.  Но тут получается count не обнулился и последовал ваш пример я так понимаю...

Comment: В конце будет тоже 0, так как я использую пост инкремент, а он приращивает единицу к переменной только после ; или ,.
когда я захожу в элсе тайм корректно присваивается в первый раз, затем count не обнуляется остается быть равным 4. и в следующую же запись когда я должен записывать .Open я попадаю опять в элсе но уже по индексу на 1 больше и происходит undefined Time

Comment: @Alex Krass, а как вы выделяете текст здесь? Я просто новичок на портале...

Comment: Да, я ступил, все правильно. Выделение через обратные кавычки ```, в английском раскладке они где буква `Ё` или `~`. Когда пишете комментарий, можете нажать еще "справка" ниже кнопки "комментировать". Там дополнительный функционал объясняется.